# Google Maps won't load inside a .php file

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Well, my issue is that when I'm trying to load a google maps script inside a **maps.php** file, it **won't** load. 
But when I change the file ending to **maps.html** it works just **fine**. 
What is causing this problem?

Regards / Denis

Comment: Without showing the code, all I can say is maybe your PHP install is fubar?

Comment: i updated the first post with the code.. :) and yeah i know there is no php code in there right now, but there will be :) (and no, even with some php-code in there is still wont work)

Comment: the server handles php without any problems. and this google maps code is actually supposed to be inside another .php file.. and thats where the problem starts. so i tried taking the code out and just trying it out alone and it still wouldn't work, but as said, it works perfectly with .html extension

Comment: and by "wouldn't work".... what exactly happens?

Comment: with the .html extension, the map loads, all the functions work and so on. (but then all the php scripts ofcourse won't work. but with the .php extension.. all the php code works. but not the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is probably why:

```
downloadUrl("loadTest.php?myAdId="+ "<?php echo $ad_id; ?>", function(data){
```

There are a few references to real PHP code, so it must be failing... HTML is just echoing the PHP code and if you tested some functions it would still break.

Comment: Thank you so much! You were right, i deleted that part, and this part:         var url = "dotsFromMap.php?ad_radius=" + details + "&ad_zoom=" + zoomLevel + "&lat=" + location.lat() + "&lon=" + location.lng() + "&ad_id=" + "<?php echo $ad_id; ?>";   Then it worked! Thank you so much! :)

        downloadUrl(url, function(doc) {    });